# How to upload a file to a node js server via HTML form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, file-handling

I have a problem with uploading a file to a node server via HTML. In the page I have this input:

```
<input type="file" id = "csvFile" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="send_data()" />
```

Then I have the send_data function that looks like this:

```
function send_data(){

    let file = document.getElementById("csvFile");
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", file, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/csv");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = () =>{

    if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200){

        console.log("done");
    }

    xhr.send();
```

}

Here there is the first problem, because the arrow function of the ready state never executes.

In any case, it's the first time I do something like this, so I don't know how I can make sure that my server gets the file and processes it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
let file = document.getElementById("csvFile").files[0];
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append("csvFile", file);
xhr.open("POST", '${your_full_address}');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    // In local files, status is 0 upon success in Mozilla Firefox
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        var status = xhr.status;
        if (status === 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)) {
            // The request has been completed successfully
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            // Oh no! There has been an error with the request!
        }
    }
};
xhr.send(formData);
```

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange